# Why can't my Windows devices browse but my iOS devices can browse?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

All Windows devices on our wireless home network are no longer able to browse the internet. The choice of browser does not matter. All iOS devices can still browse without problems.

I have tried the following while working with an elevated command prompt:

Ipconfig /release Ipconfig /renew Ipconfig /flushdns

None of those commands changed anything permanently although on a couple of occasions, the /flush temporarily allowed me to browse but it didn't last more than a few minutes.

Also tried,

Netstop dnscache

in combination with ipconfig /flushdns

Without success

Checked internet options and confirmed that it is not using a proxy.

Also confirmed that it is automatically getting an ip address and a dns server address.

No viruses found on any of the windows laptops and no rootkits either.

I can ping an IP address but not a URL.

Not sure what to try next. Ideas???

Thanks,

Randy

Comment: On a PC, try manually setting another DNS server, like say Google's: 8.8.8.8

Comment: Whats your IP range look like? Pulling valid IPs in that range? Can you ping out? Errors? Ping gateway? Reboot router/ modem? Can the router see your Windows devices? Ping LOCALHOST and 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Rebooting the router and modem had no effect but manually setting the DNS to use 8.8.8.8 on each device has allowed the browsers to work once again.  Pinging out toan ip address always worked but pinging a URL didn't until I changed the DNS address.

Answer (score 1):

Change the DNS settings on your wireless router. Or, set the alternate DNS on the devices are not permitted on the IP address of DNS names.

Comment: Setting an alternate DNS address worked.  Upon examining the DNS settings on the router I see that it was corrupted.  No idea how it happened though but thanks very much for the advice.